# I asked a snow-related question. Why was it closed and deleted?

Tags: support, on-off-topic, closed-questions, close-reasons, deleted-questions

I don't like biking in deep snow.

I asked and self-answered a question:  ["Will it snow in my city? If so, when, and how much?"](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/13757/will-it-snow-in-my-city-if-so-when-and-how-much).  I am curious:  Why was it closed and deleted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question was closed because it is not a cycling related question.  It is a question about how to forecast weather.

As such it is not appropriate on Bicycles.SE